# Is it safe to use guitar polish everywhere on the guitar?

Tags: electric-guitar, maintenance

I have owned my first electric guitar for half a year and have only been cleaning it with a damp cloth (without any cleaning agent). Since I'm going to change strings, I think it might be a good time to clean everything up.

I watched [a video about how to clean a guitar](http://www.ehow.com/video_4396406_clean-fender-stratocaster-guitar.html). He used a guitar polish everywhere on his guitar. Is it safe to do so? Does it depend on the finish of the guitar? Do I need to pay attention to the ingredient of the polish?

Sorry I'm throwing so many questions at once, but it's my first guitar so I'm a bit nervous :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are essentially two types of finishes that are used on guitars these days: Nitrocellulose and Polyurethane. There are others, such as waterborne finishes, but I'm not going to cover them here since they aren't very common on mainstream instruments. Nitro is a relic from the old days--but a couple of larger manufacturers such as Gibson and Fender still use them on some of their vintage reissue guitars. Nitro is very picky and doesn't age well. Poly is poly :D--if you've ever finished your deck then you've probably used it and seen how durable it can be. Polyurethane is very durable and you can clean it with slightly more abrasive chemicals--although I don't recommend it.

If you want the most out of your finish--whether polyurethane or the finicky nitrocellulose--then you should definitely pay attention to what's in your guitar polish. I personally don't use polish frequently at all. Instead I use some alcohol and a little distilled water on a damp cloth to clean the sweat and grime off my instrument. Then, whenever I do a complete ground-up restring I will wipe the body and fretboard down really well, then shine the body up a little with some polish and finish with a healthy dosage of mineral oil on the fretboard.

Your fretboard, depending on what woods it is constructed out of, should be paid special attention to. Rosewood, for example, is a very resilient wood but it can greatly benefit from an occasional rubdown with some mineral oil. I use [Gerlitz Guitar Honey](http://www.gerlitzusa.com/prd_honey.html) with much success. Mineral oil will bring out some beautiful colors in Brazilian Rosewood and other *unfinished* fretboard woods. A finished fretboard can be treated exactly like the guitar's body. To clean a fretboard, you can use naptha, or common lighter fluid, to cut through the gunk and grease or one of the many other techniques described by answers to [this question](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/1553/cleaning-the-fretboard-of-an-electric-guitar).

In summary, be careful what you put on the body of your guitar. Stay away from very abrasive petroleum based chemicals, and certainly anything too basic or acidic. You shouldn't need a chemistry degree to understand what a polish will do to your instrument, but you will need to understand the general ideas I have tried to outline here.

Comment: "Nitro is very picky and doesn't age well" It ages fine if reasonable care is taken with the finish. I sold my '78 Les Paul Custom last year that'd I had since it was new and it looked the same as it did when I bought it. My '68 Martin D-35 looks very nice even though it's obvious the finish has become thinner as its aged - the grain is more obvious underneath the finish now. Periodic cleaning with good polish and keeping it out of extreme heat and cold goes a long way toward preserving a finish.

Answer (score 1):

It sure depends on the finish of the guitar.
For example, I have a Fender Stratocaster with a maple fretboard and I use [Mr. C's Spray Detailer](http://www.pignoseamps.com/?disp=detail&subcat=cleaners&id=315). And I use it everywhere in this guitar.
But, when it comes to my Acoustic guitar which has a rosewood fretboard, I use [Gibson Luthier's Choice Fretboard Conditioner](http://www.gibson.com/en-us/Divisions/Gibson%20Gear/Accessories/Instrument%20Care%20Products/).
These are just examples of course.