# What household materials are safe to use for cleaning and conditioning a guitar?

Tags: guitar, maintenance

I would like to know what household materials are safe to use for cleaning and conditioning guitar body, neck, fret board, and strings.

I am thinking rubbing alcohol (99% Isopropyl alcohol), olive oil, flaxseed oil, vinegar. I have no experience, so I would appreciate some input.

My current guitar has rosewood fingerboard, glossy maple neck and glossy painted body and regular electric steel strings.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Never ever use rubbing alcohol on the guitar! That's going to be one of the best ways to strip the surface! This may not matter acoustically on the body of an electric guitar, but at best it will not look good.

For cleaning the fretboard, we have an excellent [post](https://music.stackexchange.com/q/1553/104) already, so I won't touch that part.

For the strings, the main thing that will help them last longer is a simple wipe down with a dry cloth after you play. What many players use in addition to this is FastFret or similar, which helps to clean, coat and protect strings from rust.